# fabricjs can works for a donout chart?

Tags: fabricjs

i try to make this with circle and use startAnge and endAngle but when i want to draw filled part with one color and other color for outside not let me ..or at least not found a way..i try to make groups..one circle for filled part and other circle in same position for outfilled part ..seems not work for me..
any ideas?
here the demo https://jsfiddle.net/mavirroco/on0xg64k/

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 40,
        left: 100,
        top: 300,
        angle: -90,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 1.5*Math.PI,
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 25,
        fill: ''
});

var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 40,
        left: 100,
        top: 300,
        angle: -90,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 1.5*Math.PI,
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 25,
        fill: ''
});

var circle3 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 40,
        left: 100,
        top: 300,
        angle: -90,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 1.5*Math.PI,
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 25,
        fill: ''
});
canvas.add(circle);
```

regards

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/on0xg64k/1/

Comment: nice code..well i was asking if can make this with just one circle maybe fill for example 75% with one color and the other 25% withother color..at center maybe a text...did you think this can be done in fabricjs..the reason that i set 3 circles is because i was trying to make over in same position all..

Answer (score 0):

Look updated fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/asturur/on0xg64k/3/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 40,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        startAngle: -0.3,
        endAngle: 0,
        stroke: '#0F0',
        strokeWidth: 25,
        fill: ''
});

var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 40,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        startAngle: 0.9,
        endAngle: -0.4,
        stroke: '#F00',
        strokeWidth: 25,
        fill: ''
});

var circle3 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 40,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        startAngle: 0.3,
        endAngle: 0.7,
        stroke: '#00F',
        strokeWidth: 25,
        fill: ''
});
var group = new fabric.Group([circle, circle2, circle3]);
canvas.add(group);
```

I think there are some discrepancy in the code that need fixing.
It looks like fabricjs uses radians instead of angle in the startAngle and endAngle property and looks like that filling is not affected by this property.

[image]